# preventing the form submit in bootstrap form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have two questions.
I am using a bootstrap form and bootstrap inbuilt validations for form-controls validations.

**Question 1**:
Is there any form property that gets set when all form-controls are valid ??

 
**Question 2**:
I want to prevent the form submit on submit button click and open a modal popup to confirm the details filled and then submit the form on confirmation click. 
In this case, `form.preventDefault()` method is not working for IE and chrome.

how to cater this thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery Validation, it works well with bootstrap.

- Declare rule:

  ```
  var $validator = $('#yourForm').validate({
  rules: {
      firstname: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 3
      },
      email: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 3,
      }
  },

  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      $(element).parent('div').addClass('has-error');
  }
  ```

  });
- Check form valid:

  var $isValid = $('.wizard-card form').valid();
- After that, handle submitting form with jquery submit:
  https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Hope it helps.